# Rails 4 link_to ..., method: :delete not working in development

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I've tried looking around at the various other questions that seem to match this issue, but my problem **only seems to arise in development mode**, which make it somewhat unique. I've ensured that `javascript_include_tag application, 'data-turbolinks-track' => true` is included in my layout. In the top of my `application.js` I include `angular`, `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` in that order, ie.

```
application.js

//= require angular
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And I've checked the output of the `link_to` tag, which is:

```
<a data-confirm="You sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/finance/portfolios/1"><img src="/assets/red-x.jpg" alt="Red x" width="12" height="12"></a>
```

Yet, for some reason **in development ONLY**, the link always generates a GET request. **In production**, it works just fine and actually goes to the correct controller and action.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Is it perhaps due to the way the assets are compiled and served in production. I've tried just about everything and am really at a loss.

Comment: Does jquery work from console in development?

Comment: It works fine from console. If I type in `$` I get `jQuery(selector, context)`